# Recommended server specification for laravel + mssql application

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, iis, windows-server

What is the recommended server specification for laravel + mssql application? because I have never try on a windows server. And is there a recommendation for vps that is used for the laravel + mssql application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you could try to use the newest windows server 2019. It is the newest windows server and contains the newest IIS 10.

Windows server could install the PHP and MySQL and working well.

More details about how to install the Laravel in the windows, you could refer to below article.

https://jimfrenette.com/2016/09/laravel-iis-windows-install/

Comment: Thanks so much, for the link. thats really help

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQLserver with Laravel, but there is no problem if the SQLserver driver can be installed

[SQLserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

However, since there is almost no root authority to use it with the hosting service, it is recommended to use the VPS that contains the driver from the beginning.